# Default method handler for send with unknown symbol

Tags: ruby

I defined a class on which I intend to call `send`:

```
class Decoder
  def Foo 
    "Decoding Foo"
  end 
end

decoder = Decoder.new
puts "Foo: '#{decoder.send :Foo}'"
# => Foo: 'Decoding Foo'
```

`Decoder` has other such methods. I would like to call `send` with a symbol that doesn't have a corresponding method defined, and have a default handler called instead.  Within this default handler, I would like to know what symbol was sent. Where `Baz` is not defined, I want this output:

```
decoder = Decoder.new
puts "Baz: '#{decoder.send :Baz}'"
# => <Unhandled Baz>
```

I tried something like this:

```
class Decoder
  def DefaultHandler
    "<Unhandled XXX>"
  end 
end

decoder = Decoder.new
puts "Baz: '#{decoder.send :Baz}'"
# => undefined method `Baz' for #<Decoder:0x7fa461882a68> (NoMethodError)
```

This doesn't work. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are not supposed to name methods with capitalized strings. Secondary, if you want to catch calls to undefined methods, you should override the [`BasicObject#method_missing`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing) method:

```
class Decoder
    def foo 
        "Decoding foo"
    end 

    def bar 
        "Decoding bar"
    end 

    def method_missing name, *args
        "<Unhandled #{name} with args passed: #{args}>"
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding method names.  Does the same rule apply to symbols, such as `:Bar`?

Comment: Ruby reserves capitalized names for constants. This is a guideline, not a strict rule, though.

Comment: While the advise is correct, here are capitalized method names such as `Array`.

Comment: @sawa `Array()`, `String()` and family, defined on `Kernel`, look like constructors, quack like constructors and swim like constructors. I spoke about rules for ordinary Ruby programmers, not Matz.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Decoder
  def method_missing m, *_
    "<Unhandled #{m}>"
  end
end

puts Decoder.new.send :SomethingUndefined
# => <Unhandled SomethingUndefined>
```